# Alternative to pandas apply function for row wise operation on dataframe columns with multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, apply, numba

I have two dataframes with multiple columns like below

head(df

```
    SCHEDULING_DC_NBR       COMMODITY_CODE          Unload_Start_Time   DOW     Dlry
0   6042.0                    SCGR                      15:15           SUN      5
1   6042.0                    SCGR                      15:30           SUN      6
2   6042.0                    SCGR                      15:45           SUN      7
3   6042.0                    SCGR                      16:15           SUN      8
4   6042.0                    SCGR                      18:30           SUN      9
```

head(config_df)

```
Node      Window               APPLICABLE_DAYS   COMMODITY_CODE  Window_start_time  
7023.0  03:15 AM to 03:16 AM            MON         SCPR                03:15   
7023.0  03:15 AM to 03:16 AM            THUR        SCPR                03:15
7023.0  03:15 AM to 03:16 AM            FRI         SCPR                03:15
6042.0  06:00 PM to 06:05 PM            SUN         SCPR                18:00   
6042.0  03:00 PM to 03:05 PM            SUN         SCGR                15:00
```

I want to apply row-wise operation on **dataframe df** to find the appropriate **Window** from config_df using some logic like below using apply function

```
def window_mapping(hist_df):
    window_times = []
    row = hist_df.copy()
    
    window_times = pd.to_datetime(config_df.loc[(config_df['Node'].values == row['SCHEDULING_DC_NBR'].values)
                                                           & (config_df['COMMODITY_CODE'].values == row['COMMODITY_CODE'].values)
                                                           & (config_df['APPLICABLE_DAYS'].str.contains(row['DOW'].values,case=False))
                                                           ,"Window_start_time"].values)

    if( len(window_times) > 0 ):
        if pd.to_datetime(row['Unload_Start_Time']) <= min(window_times):
             return config_df.loc[(config_df['Node'] == row['SCHEDULING_DC_NBR'])  & (config_df['COMMODITY_CODE'] == row['COMMODITY_CODE']) & ( config_df['Window_start_time'] == min(window_times).strftime('%H:%M')),"Window"].values[0], row['DOW']
            
        elif pd.to_datetime(row['Unload_Start_Time']) >= max(window_times):
             return config_df.loc[(config_df['Node'] == row['SCHEDULING_DC_NBR']) & (config_df['COMMODITY_CODE'] == row['COMMODITY_CODE']) & ( config_df['Window_start_time'] == max(window_times).strftime('%H:%M')),"Window"].values[0], row['DOW']
            
        else:
            # Find the difference of row['Unload_Start_Time'] with all window_times and get the smallest +ve difference
            differences = {}
            for times in window_times:
                
                differences[times] = (pd.to_datetime(row['Unload_Start_Time']) - times).seconds/60
            return config_df.loc[(config_df['Node'] == row['SCHEDULING_DC_NBR']) & (config_df['COMMODITY_CODE'] == row['COMMODITY_CODE']) & ( config_df['Window_start_time'] == min(differences, key=differences.get).strftime('%H:%M')),"Window"].values[0], row['DOW']
            
    else:
        return '',''
```

Below is the apply function used to **apply** the above function

```
a['Processed_window'],a['Processed_DOW'] = zip(*a.apply(window_mapping,axis=1))
```

The **final output** after applying the window_mapping function looks like below

```
SCHEDULING_DC_NBR   COMMODITY_CODE Unload_Start_Time   DOW   Processed_window      Processed_DOW
6042.0                   SCGR            15:15         SUN    03:00 PM to 03:05 PM    SUN
6042.0                   SCGR            15:30         SUN    03:00 PM to 03:05 PM    SUN
6042.0                   SCGR            15:45         SUN    03:00 PM to 03:05 PM    SUN
6042.0                   SCGR            16:15         SUN    03:00 PM to 03:05 PM    SUN
6042.0                   SCGR            18:30         SUN    06:00 PM to 06:05 PM    SUN
```

Using the apply function it took below time just for 1000 records. My original dataframe contains more than 120K records.

```
**14.9 s ± 160 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)**
```

Is there a better way to do this operation. I know np.where and np.select could be used for conditional checking. however, I am doing more than just conditional checking by calculating a list and a dictionary for my checking which are used for computation. A detailed solution or approach would really help.

Comment: If you want to do it faster you should change your model to fit with functions related to the pandas series and then do all the process column-wise. to do so, first, you need to generate a column for. window_times which I believe you can create it with merging to df with those 3 criteria. then for each, if else in your function again create a new column and compare column-wise. I hope it helps.